# Android MPAndroidChart PieChart not getting hole tranparent color

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

In my Android application I implemented an MPAndroidChart PieChart. I'm getting everything according to my requirement. But I am not able to prevent transparent color inside Pie chart. How do I solve this issue?

This is my sample code

```
    mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setHoleColorTransparent(true);
    mChart.setHoleRadius(50f);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(10);

    // enable rotation of the chart by touch
    mChart.setRotationAngle(0);
    mChart.setRotationEnabled(false);
    mChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just comment-out this line:

```
//mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll check

Comment: Thank you so much nabil. You saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Define a new color in **colors.xml**

```
<color name="Transparent">#00000000</color>
```

then set the Transparent color to your pie chart hole:

```
pieChart.setHoleColor(getColor(R.color.Transparent));
```